# controlTextDidChange not triggered when NStextField text changes

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift5

I'm trying to hook to the text change event of an `NSTextField`.I have added the `NSTextFieldDelegate` ,set the delegate on the ViewDidLoad event.But this function is not triggered when I change the textfield.I'm using `Swift 5`,seems there is no need to override the controlTextDidChange like in `Swift 4`.What I'm I doing wrong ?

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate,NSFontChanging,NSTextFieldDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var text_watermark: NSTextField!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        text_watermark.delegate=self
    }
  func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
    // Do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and `controlTextDidChange ` is called.

Comment: @Willeke Which is the SWIFT version you are using ?

Comment: I tried Swift 5, 4.2 and 4.

Comment: @Willeke I managed to fix it using an extension like this `extension ViewController: NSControlTextEditingDelegate {
     func controlTextDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {` Don't know what is wrong.